# Getting Error while processing simple csv file

Tags: csv, azure-data-lake, u-sql

I'm trying to Process  [Source](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AtFu80OEpmZKgRXDoL-QPOrVTgBO) file, with below usql script, but getting error while submitting job to ADLA as screen shot below.

I thought it would be csv issue created from openoffice, so created again from excel
but result are same. would appreciate if anyone can provide suggestion about what i'm missing here.

```
DECLARE @in  string = "/output/SearchLog-from-Data-Lake-cp.csv";
DECLARE @out string = "/output/trckout.csv";

 @CustData =
     EXTRACT CustomerUniqueID   int     ,
     CusLocationID              int   ,
     [PIM]                      int   ,
     AgeGender                  string  ,
     Mood                       string  ,
//     StartDate                  DateTime,
     ImagePath                  string  ,
//     EndDate                    DateTime,
     OutletName                 string  ,
     OutletStreet               string  ,
     OutletCity                 string  ,
     OutletState                string  ,
     OutletAreaCode             string  ,
     OutletCountry              string  ,
     Outletlandmark             string  ,
     OutletWeather              string  ,
     BrandName                  string  ,
     BrandStreet                string  ,
     BrandCity                  string  ,
     BrandState                 string  ,
     BrandAreaCode              string  ,
     BrandCountry               string  ,
     Brandlandmark              string  ,
     CamLocName                 string  ,
     CamAddress                 string  ,
     CamZone                    string  ,
     CamContactName             string  ,
     CamEmailID                 string  ,
     CamPhone                   string  ,
     CamNotloc                  string  ,
     CamNotZon                  string  ,
     CamNotContctName           string  ,
     CamNotPhone                string  ,
     CamNotEmailID              string  ,
     CamSMSNot                  string

     FROM @in
//     USING Extractors.Csv(skipFirstNRows:1);
USING Extractors.Csv();


OUTPUT @CustData   
    TO @out
      USING Outputters.Csv();
```

**ERROR**
[image]

Comment: The error says you have a column count mismatch...that is probably your issue.  You can insert NULL or empty string, but you cannot just skip over columns that are lacking source data.

Comment: Concur w Tim.  Your source file has 37 columns.  Your EXTRACT statement has 35 columns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The input has the data for 1 column - OutletLandmark - in 3 columns:

- NEAR,TRIBUNE,CHOWNK.

which results in the column count mismatch.  The input data needs to be fixed.